# Extjs - Display nested objects in Property grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6.5

I am trying to display my JSON in a `propertygrid` where I have nested level of JSON structure. As per to the property grid documentation the only types supported are boolean, string, date, number. So am only able to see the flatten level information and not the nested object.

Wanted to know if there is any configuration in `propertygrid` which will allow me to display and edit the nested information ? or any other component available which will be helpful instead of `propertygrid`

Below is the sample config and [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3edu&view/editor):

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
    title: 'Properties Grid',
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    source: {
        "allowBlank": "My Object",
        "minValue": 1,
        "maxValue": 10,
        "itemDetails": {
            "name": "name 1",
            "type": "Object"
        },
        "Description": "A test object"
    },
    sourceConfig: {
        allowBlank: {
            displayName: 'Required'
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Fiddle is down.

Comment: yes currently no examples are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use editable column tree:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "allowBlank",
            value: "My Object",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "minValue",
            value: "1",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "maxValue",
            value: 10,
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "itemDetails",
            value: "",
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: "name",
                value: "name 1",
                leaf: true
            }, {
                text: "type",
                value: "Object",
                leaf: true
            }]
        }, {
            text: "Description",
            value: "A test object",
            leaf: true
        }]
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    height: 200,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    plugins: {
        cellediting: {
            clicksToEdit: 2,
            listeners: {
                beforeedit: function (editor, context, eOpts) {
                    if (!context.record.isLeaf()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    var column = context.column;
                    switch (typeof context.record.get('value')) {
                    case "string":
                        column.setEditor({
                            xtype: 'textfield'
                        });
                        return;
                    case "number":
                        column.setEditor({
                            xtype: 'numberfield'
                        });
                        return;
                    //...
                    //...
                    default:
                        column.setEditor({
                            xtype: 'textfield'
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    },
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        text: 'Headers',
        dataIndex: 'text'
    }, {
        text: 'Value',
        dataIndex: 'value',
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but is there any other approach instead of `treepanel`. I would like to avoid it only this component.

Comment: Hm, I don't know any other representation of nested object as a tree. Why would you like to avoid tree component?

Comment: By avoiding I meant that I had kept it as a last option for displaying the JSON in nested tree structure. `Propertygrid` was giving a flexibility of taking entire json and avoiding the creation of stores as it created internally but displays flat levels structure other than that tree is also a option. Just wanted to know the available options and you have given the answer for it.

Comment: Treegrid doesn't work for you? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hrm&view/editor